# How to tell hibernate to print the column name instead of column number in the log?

Tags: java, hibernate

I was able the get the below log

```
Hibernate: insert into ORGANIZATIONALUNITCATALOG (ID, SYSTEMID) values (null, ?)
[main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.LongType  - binding '0' to parameter: 1
```

after specifying the log4j properties as

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.sql=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=DEBUG
```

Is there a way to tell hibernate **3.2.x** to show the binding column name instead of the column number? i.e. I'd like to see the log line as

```
[main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.LongType  - binding '0' to parameter: SYSTEMID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE` should do it.

If you still have problems, try enabling trace on these too

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.engine.query=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=TRACE
```

In addition make sure you have TRACE logging enabled in your config.  Many times default config files will set logging at DEBUG as the lowest.

Comment: are you sure trace is turned on, have you tried to trace one of your core classes (i.e log.trace("is trace on"))?

Comment: yes...i added my own trace log which is being printed in the log but nothing from hibernate...but i see INFO from hibernate

Comment: you see INFO, but don't see DEBUG?  Isn't the SQL query at the DEBUG level, are you seeing that?  i'd try backing up the log4j file, then doing a quick trace everything log just to make sure something in there isn't killing trace messages

Comment: You may check out this bug, it is related to the version you say you are using http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2835

Answer (score 0):

Use `log4j.logger.org.hibernate=debug`

Comment: this gives you the query, but not the binding